# How to get all pages of a custom content type to be displayed using a custom view?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8, how can I get all pages of a custom content type "MyPage" to be displayed using a custom view "MyView"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Structure -> Views -> Add a view (`/admin/structure/views/add')
2. **View Settings**: Show **Content** of type **MyPage**.

I suggest reading the [Views documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/overview).

Comment: Thank you. I have read that documentation, and watched numerous tutorials, but I find the details of the Views module extremely difficult to grasp. My "MyPage" pages still appear the same after using your procedure to apply my "MyView" custom view, so I have asked [a further question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251633/on-a-content-page-that-references-a-taxonomy-term-how-can-i-display-only-conten) which is directed at what I'm actually trying to achive.

Comment: When you create a view as I described, it does not change how nodes (pages) of the content type are displayed; instead, it creates a new page that lists all the nodes (pages) of that content type.

Comment: Understood, and I was able to do that previously by checking "Create a page" when I added the view. But I wish to assign a custom view to all nodes (pages) of a custom content type, not just create a single new page.

Comment: You can create multiple pages from the "Page" screen; you need to put a wildcard in the path and use arguments.  But it's probably easier to use Panels if that's what you want to do.

Comment: You can create a views block and add the block to existing pages of your liking by using the available restrictions within the block settings.

Comment: It sounds like what he is asking for is changing the 'default' display of a node, arranging the fields and field formatters and optionally providing a twig template. You don't need Views for that. Page Manager / Panels sounds like a better fit than Views.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Structure -> Views -> Add a view (`/admin/structure/views/add')
2) In filter criteria select Content:content type (= MyPage)